# PHP: Are there Server Side Resource Loaders? (like Mediawiki)

Tags: php, server-side, server-side-scripting, resource-loading

Are there any Resource Loaders avaiable that works server-side? Is that called Ressource Loader? I like the Ressource Loader of Mediawiki very much. Is there a project to use their Ressource Loader standalone?

For me, a Ressource Loader is a script, that packs multible js-Files into one, compress them and cache them. Then send it to the client.

Edit:Something like [assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic). Thanks for mentioning in the comments.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please specify what exactly you understand a "Resource Loader" to be.

Comment: Are you talking about [assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic) and simliar projects?

Comment: @Rangad: Yes, something like this. I will take a look at this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/). Assetic seems a bit complicated for me.

**Minify** can:

- Compress CSS and JS, there seems to be something for compressing HTML too.
- You only need to change the urls for example /min/f=js.js instand of js.js

But there is a bug. You have to remove every realpath(...)-function in /min/lib/Minify/Controller/MinApp.php.